# Duplicate data/value for Named Query Inner join tables with same column name

Tags: java, mysql, sql, named-query

I'm trying to join three tables: Student, BorrowedBook, Books using the named query below

```
List< Student > stuList= new ArrayList< Student >( );
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( );
sb.append( "select s.studentId, s.name, s.lastName, b.name " );
sb.append( "from student s " );
sb.append( "inner join borrowedbook c on 
            s.studentId = c.studentId " );
sb.append( "inner join books b on c.bookId = b.bookId " );

Query query = getSession( ).createSQLQuery( sb.toString( ) );
query.setProperties( Student.class );

List< Object[] > searchResults = query.list( );
```

However, when I check the value of b.name in the searchResults on debugging mode, it gets the value of s.name. Meaning, b.name is getting the same name as s.name even though it is supposed to have it's own name. I dont know what's the problem here, I even gave them alias to differentiate between them.

Comment: You mentioned that you tried using an alias here, but I don't see this attempt anywhere.  Anyway, in fact this is one way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should alias the two `name` columns to different things:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( );
sb.append( "select s.studentId, s.name as student_name, s.lastName, " );
sb.append( " b.name as book_name " );
sb.append( "from student s " );
sb.append( "inner join borrowedbook c on s.studentId = c.studentId " );
sb.append( "inner join books b on c.bookId = b.bookId " );
```

Then access your result set using the column names `student_name` and `book_name`.

Comment: I get an error. It's too long for the whole stack

Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10150][10300][4.14.137] Invalid parameter: Unknown column name NAME. ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:661)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:103)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fb.a(fb.java:2122)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.findColumnX(ResultSet.java:1932)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:1704)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.getString(WSJdbcResultSet.java:2467)

Comment: 00000044 SystemErr     R org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)

Comment: I don't think this error is being caused only by my suggested changes, assuming you are actually running it as a raw query.  I think the problem is happening somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Strawberry There are no errant commas AFAIK.  Where do you see them?

Comment: @timbiegeleisen s.lastname, - ah, I see the other column now